# Why i am not able to find index of an element in the vector?

Tags: c++

I am getting the `max` element right but not index of maximum element.index of element is coming out to be equal to `max` element.

```
long int maxi=*max_element(segments.begin(),segments.end());

long int index=*find(segments.begin(),segments.end(),maxi);
```

Comment: yes, because it **is** the maximal element. Read the documentation of `find()`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's trivially answerable by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
long int index=find(segments.begin(),segments.end(),maxi) - segments.begin();
```

Find returns an *iterator* to the maximum element, which for vectors behaves mostly like a pointer. What you were doing was dereferencing it (which just gets you what it points to, the maximum element). Instead, compute the distance between that iterator and the start iterator to get the index.